# How to call a native method with a std::vector as argument and retrieve the native object in wrapped class

Tags: c++-cli

I have a native C++ method, from external unchangable DLL, that expects a std::vector as a argument with 2 native objects. (for example sake, it's an image library returning width/height of a 2 images)

I would like the native objects in the std::vector to be referenced in my own wrapped MyManagedImageObj.

Somehow the std::vector seems to copy values and has no way to add pointers (correct?); so after calling the NativeMethod; I need to copy the properties (width/height) back again to MyManagedImageObj.

I thought about first declaring the std::vec and getting the pointer of the results and put that in MyManagedImageObj as a pointer. But if I understand it correctly std::vector will clean that native memory up once out of scope. (my c++ experience is 1 week; c# long time)

Is there a better way to do this without reassigning the properties one by one?

Ej

The code looks like this:

```
//create managed object that wraps also native pointer. 
MyManagedImageObj^ obj1 = gcnew MyManagedImageObj();
MyManagedImageObj^ obj2 = gcnew MyManagedImageObj();

//keep list of result
List<MyManagedImageObj^>^ resultList;
resultList->Add(obj1);
resultList->Add(obj2);

//call to native method. Dereference pointers of native wrapped objects... not working? 
std::vector<DLLNativeImageObj> nativeImageVec { *obj1->GetInstance(), *obj2->GetInstance() };
bool result = otherNativePtr->NativeMethod(nativeImageVec);

//we still need copy it over results now to 'our' managed objects.  
int i = 0;
for (DLLNativeImageObj c : nativeImageVec)
{
    resultList[i]->ImageHeight = c.imageHeight;
    resultList[i]->ImageWidth = c.imageWidth;
    ++i;
}
```

The MyManagedImageObj class looks like this:

```
//MyManagedImageObj.h

public ref class MyManagedImageObj
{
protected: 
    DLLNativeImageObj* m_Instance;
public:
    MyManagedImageObj(DLLNativeImageObj* instance)
        : m_Instance(instance)
    {
    };
    
    ~MyManagedImageObj() //destructor will be called whenever we do 'delete' 
    {
        if (m_Instance != nullptr)
        {
            delete m_Instance;
        }
    }
    
    !MyManagedImageObj() //finalizer, called by the garbage collector when it's destroys the wrapper object. So safety check to dispose unmanaged item. 
    {
        if (m_Instance != nullptr)
        {
            delete m_Instance;
        }
    }

    DLLNativeImageObj* GetInstance() //return the pointer to the unmanaged object
    {
        return m_Instance;
    }
    
    property uint32_t ImageWidth
        {
        public:
            uint32_t get()
            {
                return m_Instance->imageWidth;
            }
        public:
            void set(uint32_t value)
            {
                m_Instance->imageWidth = value;
            }
        }

        property uint32_t ImageHeight
        {
        public:
            uint32_t get()
            {
                return m_Instance->imageHeight;
            }
        public:
            void set(uint32_t value)
            {
                m_Instance->imageHeight = value;
            }
        }
};

//MyManagedImageObj.cpp
MyManagedImageObj::MyManagedImageObj(new DLLNativeImageObj())
    {
        // new keyword important: it returns a pointer to the location and does not get deleted when out of scope. Manual delete is required. 
    }
```

Comment: ImageHeigth is a property wrapping imageHeight. 
I used “I” vs “i” to not get confused myself

Comment: I've added the code from the class. Hope this clearifies my question. It's perhaps more a 'how to design CLI' code question. My assumption is that because the std::vector manages it's own memory and the nativeMethod requires a std::vector i'm sort of obliged to copy back the fields one by one afterwards.. I can't pass in my own pointer to a native object I instantiated..  But i'm not sure here. Hope I have been able to bring it across.

Comment: I missed it in the first pass, the code dereferences the returned GetInstance() pointer.  In other words, the vector contains copies of the native objects.  You can only avoid it by using `vector<DLLNativeImageObj*>`.  Which does require changing the native function.